# How to configure MAME command line for Windows?

Tags: emulation, mame, windows-xp

Do you know know how to configure MAME command line for Windows?

I'm setting up a Windows XP box to use on an arcade project.

I've always used MAMEUI for playing MAME ROMs, it's a great emulator with plenty of settings that you can manage through a user interface.

Now I'm trying to achieve similar results by using the MAME command line emulator, because this is what front ends such as mGalaxy or Hyperspin require.
But I can't find a way to configure it in any aspect, whatsoever, as I was able to do with MAMEUI.

These are some of the emulation properties I would like to configure for the MAME command line:

- Video mode
- Aspect ratio
- Emulation speed
- Controller setup
- etc…

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The mame.exe (or mame64.exe) has extensive command line help built in. Just open up a command prompt, navigate to your MAME directory and type "mame -showusage" for a list of them.

The most basic command line would be:

```
mame.exe [gamename]
```

You can also get a list of configuration options with:

```
mame.exe -showconfig
```

Which will list what your configuration is set to. Finally the best way to control all of these settings is with a config file (as your command line can get extremely long, maybe too long) so you can create a new config file using:

```
mame.exe -createconfig
```

This will create a default mame.ini file in the same directory as your executable then you can edit it with a text editor to your liking. The INI file values are somewhat self explanatory but then you can supplement it with the documentation from the official site [here](http://wiki.mamedev.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions)

Hope that helps!